# Cannot create inner bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean]

Tags: java, spring-security

so I have a class for user details

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class TimexUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired private UserService userService;

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        TimexUser user = userService.getUserByUsername(username);
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();       
        for (String authority : user.getAuthorities())
            authorities.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(authority));
        return new User(username, user.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
    } 
}
```

and the xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/projects/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/projects/add/**" access="hasRole('manager')" />
        <form-login />
    </http>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yonder.timex" />

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customUserDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

and I get the error

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type
>   [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean]
>   while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on
>   object creation; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve
>   reference to bean 'customUserDetailsService' while setting bean
>   property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Injection of
>   autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private com.yonder.timex.service.UserService
>   com.yonder.timex.TimexUserDetailsService.userService; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   matching bean of type [com.yonder.timex.service.UserService] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

the basic problem is that i want to give an authentication provider to my user details service and I cannot do that.

Thanks a lot, Tranca

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from somewhere else.
I didn't set the right order for bean creation therefore this error